# WritableImage.WritePixels(), How resolve exception "insufficient buffer size"?

Tags: c#

I want to create a ImageSource object with a WritableImage.
My image is compose of multiple others images.
But when I call WritePixels method, I have this exception :

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in PresentationCore.dll but was not handled in user code.
>   Additional information: insufficient buffer size.

Here is my code :

```
private class Sprite
    {
        private int
            m_x,
            m_y,
            m_pHeight,
            m_pWidth,
            m_stride;
        private byte[] m_pixels;

        public Sprite (BitmapImage bimg, int x, int y)
        {
            m_x = x;
            m_y = y;
            m_pHeight = bimg.PixelHeight;
            m_pWidth = bimg.PixelWidth;

            //calculate stride
            m_stride = m_pWidth * ((bimg.Format.BitsPerPixel + 7) / 8);

            // Create data array to hold source pixel data
            m_pixels = new byte[m_stride * m_pHeight];

            // Copy source image pixels to the data array
            bimg.CopyPixels(m_pixels, m_stride, 0);
        }

        public void WritePixel (WriteableBitmap wbm)
        {
            wbm.WritePixels(
                new System.Windows.Int32Rect(m_x, m_y, m_pWidth, m_pHeight),
                m_pixels, m_stride, 0);
        }
    }
```

How to resolve this exception ?

Comment: You are not showing the code that calls this method.  Only really obvious failure mode for this exception is that you called the Sprite() constructor with an invalid BitmapImage.  Add more checking so this can't happen: if (m_pHeight <= 0) throw new ArgumentException().  Not the only problem afaict, you are also not checking that the sprite fits in the bitmap (m_x + m_pWidth <= wbm.Width), but that generates another exception.

Comment: @HansPassant I have already check if the bitmap is valid and m_x + m_Width is <= wbm.Width. It's something else.